# Не всегда срабатывает MouseLeave ивент

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется фигура:

```
<Ellipse x:Name="CIBackground" Fill="#FF3A4047" Height="44" Margin="757,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseLeave="CIBackground_MouseLeave" MouseEnter="CIBackground_MouseEnter"/>
```

В коде определены методы, на которые ссылаются события. Всё работает корректно, однако не всегда срабатывает MouseLeave. Подскажите, как это исправить или как сделать проверку положения указателя мыши (на элементе он или нет)?

Comment: Вы мышь там нигде не захватываете? Иначе она, конечно, никогда не покинет пределы контрола (логически, а не физически)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    private void MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.MouseDevice.DirectlyOver != {твой элемент})
        {
            {действия, которые требуются при MouseLeave}
            return;
        }
   }
```